# Configure RequestHandler Between 2 Solr Shards

Tags: solr

I have 2 shards :

- 127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core1
- 127.0.0.1:8984/solr/core1

I can query both shards with : "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/selectq=*:*&indent=true&shards=127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core1,127.0.0.1:8984/solr/core1&fl=id,name&wt=xml"

Response :

```
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="fl">id,name</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">3007WFP</str>
    <str name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">VA902B</str>
    <str name="name">ViewSonic VA902B - flat panel display - TFT -19</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I want to query just the first shard and receive response from both.
"Rather than require users to include the shards parameter explicitly, it is usually preferred to configure this parameter as a default in the RequestHandler section of solrconfig.xml."

Shard 1 (Query/ Response)

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/selectq=*:*&fl=id,name&wt=xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="fl">id,name</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">3007WFP</str>
    <str name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Shard 2 (Query/ Response)

```
curl "http://localhost:8984/solr/core1/select?q=*:*&fl=id,name&wt=xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="fl">id,name</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">VA902B</str>
    <str name="name">ViewSonic VA902B - flat panel display - TFT - 19"</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

After adding to the first Node (solrconfig.xml):

```
<requestHandler name="/selectdistributed" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <str name="shards">127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core1,127.0.0.1:8984/solr/core1</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The following query is only returning the document from the first node and not from both nodes as expected.

curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/selectq=*:*&fl=id,name&wt=xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="fl">id,name</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">3007WFP</str>
    <str name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Is there something else i need to add ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your new `requestHandler` with a path of `/selectdistributed`, but you're still querying `/select`:

```
<requestHandler name="/selectdistributed" class="solr.SearchHandler">
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your `curl` command:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*:*&fl=id,name&wt=xml"
                                       ^^^^^^
```

So you're still querying against the old endpoint, not the new one you have defined.

Comment: In the following question : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076481/how-to-query-solr-shard/73371817#73371817"

The example said " This will add shards=somehost:port1/solr,somehost:port2/solr to the query string of all the requsts that go through that handler."

When i query : curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/selectdistributed?q=*:*"


I receive the following error :     "msg":"Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html...

Comment: That's because there's an error on one of your servers - check the server log to see exactly what the error is. The configuration might not have been loaded as you think it has (so you're getting a 404 error thrown by the servlet container, for example).

Comment: I had checked the server logs.I have the same message.

 sorg.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html

Comment: Yes, it's telling you that the remote server it connected to throws an error when it's trying to query it.

Comment: The request handler should only be configure in one or both nodes ? 

<requestHandler name="/selectdistributed" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <str name="shards">127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core1,127.0.0.1:8984/solr/core1</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>